# .htacces and non-www www redirects

Tags: wordpress, redirect, web, https

I try to make a website and get correct redirects. However whatever i'm trying does not seem to work. My website is hosted on www.tetedelacourse.eu. Both https://www. and http://www. work and the site is visible. However the non-www url is not visible, it results in the error "ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT". However the http:// version does redirect to the https:// version.

I did a lot of search work already and tried various options. It seems to me the problems lies in redirects but the suggestions returned on google do not solve my problem.

What have i done so far? Completely reinstalled the site and a new wordpress, but this did not solve anything.

Resetted my .htacces file to:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Added the following line to the .htacces file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tetedelacourse.eu [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.tetedelacourse.eu/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I just don't know what to do anymore. I built several sites with Wordpress but this always automatically worked. Does anyone know more???

Thanks for the effort in advance,

Rick

Answer (score 0):

www.tetedelacourse.eu points to **34.240.160.162** [hosting-1b.mijndomein-ws.nl]

tetedelacourse.eu points to **34.249.138.199**

It's a DNS issue, not htaccess or SSL.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Good that you managed to point me in a different direction. I checked the DNS tables but can't find out why they point to different locations. For another website with the same hosting provider everything works fine and the tables are set up the same. Somehow I can't find the reference to .162 IP in the tables. I probably need to ask my hosting provider whats up. Thanks for your help, if you have any other suggestions I'd be glad to hear them :)!